# npm run dev fails in fresh laravel project

Tags: laravel, npm

NPM run dev fails in a new laravel project.

Its says its has problems in my resources\app.js but this file is empty :|

i tryed:

- installing older npm version
- installing babel version recommended by other questions
- updating composer
- Empty cach
- rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install

**Here is the error in term:**

```
> @ dev /Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten
> npm run development


> @ development /Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                             16:39:49

 error  in ./resources/js/app.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Package exports for '/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets' do not define a '.' subpath
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:485:15)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/debug.js:8:33)
    at Module._compile (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:11:14)
    at Module._compile (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at requireModule (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:165:12)
    at loadPreset (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:83:17)
    at createDescriptor (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at /Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at /Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:58:104
    at cachedFunction (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:62:27)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/gensync/index.js:244:28)
    at sync (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/gensync/index.js:84:14)
    at presets (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:29:84)
    at mergeChainOpts (/Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:320:26)
    at /Users/sebastiantramper/code/uniekegerechten/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:283:7

 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

       Asset     Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install` first?

Comment: Yes, i also tryed to run rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install

Comment: I just did a fresh install (`laravel new project`) and ran the commands without any problem. Laravel 6.2,  Node 8.12.0 and npm 6.4.1 on Windows. My app.js file wasn't empty. It had the a single line (`require('./bootstrap');`)

Answer (score 0):

After updating Node js it worked.

Comment: It's happend to me today, I've spent my time in order to fix same issue as you but nothing happend.
What I've done:
- Updating nodejs to the latest version
- Using the fresh template (im using Vuexy Laravel Template which is created by their teams)
- And others I found at github issues or stackoverflow.

Before the error appears, I've succesfully install the template, but a day after that, I changed the template configuration (like Copyright text, Logo, App name, etc) and it's wont work anymore, even I start form zero (using fresh template again) it still doesn't work.